# How to make helm-mark-ring/helm-imenu follow current candidate

Tags: helm, imenu, mark-ring, follow-mode

When I use `helm-mark-ring` or `helm-imenu`, I would like to jump to the current candidate automatically in the other buffer while keeping the helm session (i.e., similar to `helm-swoop`).
I tried the following codes mentioned on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emacs-helm/US8FWnfRu5o), but didn't work for me.

```
(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook #'(lambda () (helm-attrset 'follow 1 helm-source-mark-ring)))
```

Result: It shows `[Display not ready]` in echo area when I change the helm candidate (by `C-n`).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs `(setq helm-follow-mode-persistent t)` and whenever you enter helm-imenu or helm-mark-ring, press `C-<up>` or `C-<down>` to follow to that line in helm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added the setq, but the helm session closed when I do C-<up or C-<down>.

Comment: That is strange, it works perfectly fine for me. Can you elaborate on what exactly happens when you press `C-<up>` or `C-<down>` ? Have you bound `C-<up>` or `C-<down>` to some other command ? 
And if you still have the add-hook command you mentioned in the post, i.e. `(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook #'(lambda () (helm-attrset 'follow 1 helm-source-mark-ring)))' , please uncomment or remove this line and reload .emacs.

Comment: More details:

For `helm-mark-ring`, it jumps to the location correctly, but the session closed when I pressed `C-<up>` or `C-<down>`.

For `helm-imenu`, I got the following error when I pressed `C-<up>` or `C-<down>`:
    `(wrong-type-argument stringp #<marker at 150961 in work.txt)`.

I removed the hook command, and I didn't redefine the key.  I will try `emacs -Q` later.

Comment: Maybe you have something in your .emacs that is messing things up. Can you think of anything in your .emacs  that is messing things up ? If not, edit the post adding the lines in your .emacs used for helm config

Comment: You are right!  The following code messed up the persistent action:
`(advice-add 'helm-execute-persistent-action :around #'dwim-helm-find-files-navigate-forward)`.  After removing that, your answer works for me now.  Thank you very much!